# How do i implement import functionality in my custom module in admin area?

Tags: admin, import, magento-2.1.3

I have created my custom module in admin area with basic CRUD operations and now all I need is to place import functionality where I have a simple table, no EAV tables here.

Let me know if there is any way to do this or any reference in the core modules.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no general import function for models. Importing is complex, many possible erros have to be caught. You'd need to develop that functionality, that'll be a few hours of work.

Comment: I have already figured that out. Thanks anyway.